# AngularJS - How to not trigger hover action (ng-mouseenter) on mobile devices and only the cilck event

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm using AngularJS, and I currently have both a hover behaviour (using ng-mouseenter and ng-mouseleave) so when you hover on my content elements, it shows content on the page, but if you click on that element (using ng-click) it should go into a detail page for that element.

I have all of these configured on the same `<div>`, and it works on desktop. But if I use my iPhone, then when I click the element, it triggers the hover action instead of the click action. It takes a second click to get to the click action, and I want it to trigger on the first click for mobile devices.

How can I achieve this?

Thanks for any help you can offer.

Comment: I also tried adding a nested <div> inside, and keeping the ng-click event on the outer div and putting the mouseenter/mouseleave events on the inner div, but that still produced the same result on phones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should emulate double click on touch devices. You can use this directive:

```
angular.module('app').directive('touchDevicesClick', function() {
  return function(scope, elem) {
    var element = angular.element(elem);
    element.on('touchstart', function(e) {
      element.triggerHandler('click')
    });
  };
})
```

or you can use `$(elem).click()` instead `element.triggerHandler('click')`